# Calculating consumed internet data from bitmap of chart

Tags: image-processing, units, data-acquisition

My internet connection has a speed drawn up by

[image]

the y axes has a scale as KB per second. and the x axes is time elapsed. if the x axes be from 0 to 40 minutes how can I calculate total consumed bytes or kilo bytes in all elapsed time. (As a mater of fact how can I integrate of this plot although I know the result will be approximately and I don't access to the real data from which this plot drawn by a software.)

Comment: And you want to use *Mathematica* to do all this?

Comment: What is the difference between the green and yellow data?  Also, without knowing the scale for the y axis you couldn't do it.

Comment: I have seen separately  before (in SE) that mathematica can import plots or figures in order to analyze them, On another hand if I have just data extracted from the plot I can do integrate by different methods for Integration over data.

Comment: the maximum of y axes is 853 KB/s but unfortunately I don't access to ticks frame. Furthermore, yellow one is upload data and green is download.

Comment: Sorry, my numbers were wrong before, edited now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
img = ImageTrim[
       Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBL2d.png"]
     , {{30, 4}, {1910, 287}}
     ]

Total[ImageData@
  ColorNegate@
   Binarize[
    ColorSeparate[img][[3]]], 2]
```

> 142017

That is the number of pixels in the plot for download data.

Vertical axis is 2.99404 KB/s/pixel.
Horizontal axis is 1.27524 secs/pixel

Total download

```
142017 (40 60 853.3)/(Times @@ ImageDimensions[img])
```

> 542237 KB

For upload the same, but isolating the yellow channel.